# How can I deploy an Ember app on Digital Ocean?

Tags: nginx, ember.js, deployment, port, digital-ocean

I have an Ember app running on port `4200` that uses an Express API on port `4500`. I have uploaded my API to:

`/var/www/my-api-domain.com/public_html/`

I have also edited the nginx `sites-available` file:

```
location /
{
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4500;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

I SSH into the server, change directory to my API, and run `node server` and this works! When I visit my IP in the browser, I see my API working properly:

http://159.203.31.72

I then ran `ember build -prod` locally and uploaded the contents of the resulting `dist` folder to:

`/var/www/my-ember-domain.com/public_html/`

I once again updated the nginx `sites-available` with:

```
location /ember
{
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4200;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

Now what? Typically, when I run the site locally, I'd run `ember server`, but the resulting files in `dist` look much different and I don't have `ember cli` installed on the server. As I read about it, that doesn't seem to be the proper approach.

When I hit http://159.203.31.72/ember in the browser, I get an nginx `502 Bad Gateway`. How can I serve my Ember app?

Answer (score 1):

`ember server` starts a development server which **should not** be used in production. Build your app using `ember build --prod`. Afterwards you will find your assets in `dist/` folder. Serve that ones with nginx and you are done. There is an example `nginx.conf` in ember-cli docs: https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#deploying-an-https-server-using-nginx-on-a-unixlinuxmacosx-machine

You could use [ember-cli-deploy](http://ember-cli-deploy.com/) if you have to set up a more complex deployment workflow.